# i don't know what i did wrong, it doesn't work, i'm trying to make a task list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--Declare the document type and version of HTML-->
<html> 
    <head><!--Information related to the decument-->
        <title>Task List</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mydesign.css">
    </head>
    <body><!--Information related to display the decument-->
        [<img src="cm1XiuT.png" alt="CounterStrike" style="width:100%;height:250pt;">][1]
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Tasks Here..." id="taskValue">
        <button id="addBtn" onclick="addTask()">add</button>
        <!--horizontal Rule-->
        <hr>

    <section id="content">
    </section>
    <script>
```

> /*creates an Array        variable tasks checks if there are any stored
>   tasks in the browser          Conditional statement - Checks IF there is
>   data stored then imports the data to the array        IF not - exitx the
>   function with an empty array      IF THERE IS  - exits the function with
>   the poplulated array*/

this is a code

```
function creatArray()
            {
                var taskArray = [];
                var tasks = localStorage.getItem("itemList");
                if(tasks != null)
                {
                /*code runs if the condition is met*/
                taskArray = JSON.parse(tasks);
            }
            return taskArray;
        }
```

> /*Addsa task to the list          Creates an array            Creates a variable to
>   store the information in the input fieldset           clears the information
>   in the input field            Pushes the task into our Array          Stores the
>   updated Tasklist in the browser           Calls the displayTask Function
>             */

```
function addTask()
            {
                var taskList = creatArray();
                var task = document.getElementById("taskValue").value;
                document.getElementById("taskValue").value = "";
                taskList.push(task);
                localStorage.setItem("itemList",JSON.stringify(taskList));
                displayTask();
            }
```

> /*Removes a task from the list            creats a variable to store the
>   correct button information.           this - as in "this"button that has been
>   clicked           creats an array             removes the task from our array and
>   defines how many items we need to remove              calls the displayTask
>   function          */

```
function removeTask()
            {
            //remove the tasks from the array
            var rID = this.getAttribute("id");
            var taskList = createArray();
            taskList.splice(rID, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("itemList",JSON,stringify(taskList));
            displayTask();
            }
```

> /*displays Tasks in the list          Creates the array of tasks          creates
>   the variable to store the list items          LOOP statement - adds HTML to
>   each list item in the array {repeats until the end of the }
>             replaces the content in the section tag with id="content"
>             creates a button array          LOOP STATMENT - adds an EvenListenerr to
>   each button in the List           */

```
function displayTask()
            {
                var taskList = createArray();
                var showTasks = "<ul>";

                for(var i=0; i < taskLIst.length; i++)
                {
                showTasks += "<li>"+taskList[i]="<button class='rmvBtn'id='"+i+"'>remove</button></li>"
            }


showTasks += "</ul>";

                document.getElementById("content"),innerHTML =showTasks;

                var btnArray = document.getElementById("rmvBtn");
                for(i =0; i < btnArray.length; 1++)
                {
                btnArray[i].addEventListener('click',removeTask);
                }
            }

            displayTask()
        </script><!--includes an external javascript file-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you move this to a fiddle?

Comment: Typo. Please learn how to open and use the developer console in your browser. There's a JavaScript error in `displayTask` where an `=` sign was typed  insteaad of `+`. When you fix this you will see the next error on the console

Answer (score 1):

Look, only javascript and html

**HTML**

```
  <div id="tasks"></div>
  <div>
     <input type="text" id="newTaskInput">
     <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tasks = []

function init() {
  tasks = load()
  renderTasks()
}

init()

function renderTasks() {
   var container = document.getElementById('tasks')
   var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()

   tasks.forEach(function(item, i) {
   var div = document.createElement('div')
   var text = document.createTextNode(item.name)
   div.appendChild(text)

   var closeBtn = document.createElement('button')
   var btnText = document.createTextNode('x')
   closeBtn.appendChild(btnText)
   closeBtn.onclick = function() {
     remove(i)
   }
   div.appendChild(closeBtn)

   frag.appendChild(div)
 })

 container.innerHTML = ""
 container.appendChild(frag)
}

function add() {
  var input = document.getElementById('newTaskInput')
  tasks.push({ name: input.value })
  renderTasks()
  save(tasks)
}

function remove(index) {
  tasks.splice(index, 1)
  renderTasks()
  save(tasks)
}


function save(data) {
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(data))
}

function load() {
  var raw = localStorage.getItem('tasks')
  if ( raw ) {
    return JSON.parse(raw)
  }
  return []
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://playcode.io/56?tabs=app.html&script.js&output)